# Ubuntu 18.04 fails to start network, netplan DHCP configuration

Tags: server, 18.04, netplan

Netplan configured for DHCP on interface ens160:

```
more /etc/netplan/01-netcfg.yaml
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    ens160:
      dhcp4: yes
```

When executing netplan restart nothing happens, only when "touching" the file or editing it and then restarting netplan/network it works, after reboot network is down also. This only happens with ubuntu 18.

Comment: After editing the file, did you do: `sudo netplan generate` followed by: `sudo netplan apply` ? Were there any errors or other clues after each command? Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: no errors, the issue is that the interface don't get an IP when we don't update the file

Answer (score 6):

Please check: `cat /usr/share/doc/netplan.io/examples/dhcp.yaml` The correct wording is dhcp4:  true. Please amend your file to:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    ens160:
      dhcp4: true
```

Follow with:

```
sudo netplan generate
sudo netplan apply
```

Reboot and let us hear your report.

Comment: I've checked the documentation and found that 'yes' or 'true' are tge same.
found examples with both options...
went and checked this myself and it doesn't make a difference

Comment: If you boot when it is not working, are there clues in the log? `dmesg | grep -e enp -e netplan`

Comment: I'm not able to get this to work either.  Its hard to paste the results of dmesg into here, but i see the "enp0s3: link becomes ready" message as the last thing. Other than that there doesn't seem to be any clear logs on why its not able to obtain an IP address.  I am running Ubuntu inside a VM, with bridged networking enabled.

Comment: Please paste the requested output here and give us the link: http://paste.ubuntu.com

Comment: still good in 2023

Answer (score 0):

I've seen something similar, ever since 18.04.3 or so.  I had to mark the interface as optional, in the `/etc/netplan/interface.yaml` file.  Then I have a script run dhclient at startup.

It's a kluge, but it got the job done.  I stumbled across this question, hoping to find a better way.